# Global custom settings in jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I develop a web application.
The backend of it is jboss 6.1.
In this environment, what is the best way to implement the following:
Some custom entries outside in a file like DEBUG or STAGE or something like this with a value which can be changed.
In the session bean I want to read this value and behave according to this setting.
In other environments, a good way to implement this is a properties file.
But is it also with jboss?
Thanks a lot in advance
Wolfgang

Comment: I prefer to have a startup servlet taking care of initialization, peeking from custom configuration files and reloading config upon GET calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If configuration is limited then you can [use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

While launching Jboss you can speficy properties using -D option.

> -Dproperty=value
>   Set a system property value. If value is a string that contains spaces, you must enclose the string in double quotes: 
>           java -Dfoo="some string" SomeClass

You can use [System.getProperty(String Key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) to access value of it.